# Recursive functions and global vs. local variables

Tags: r, recursion, global-variables, local-variables

I'm writing a recursive function in R, and I want it to modify a global variable such that I know how many instances of the function have been called. I don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
i <- 1

testfun <- function( depth= 0 ) {

  i <- i + 1
  cat( sprintf( "i= %d, depth= %d\n", i, depth ) )
  if( depth < 10 ) testfun( depth + 1 )
}
```

Here is the output:

```
i= 2, depth= 0
i= 2, depth= 1
i= 2, depth= 2
i= 2, depth= 3
i= 2, depth= 4
i= 2, depth= 5
i= 2, depth= 6
i= 2, depth= 7
i= 2, depth= 8
i= 2, depth= 9
i= 2, depth= 10
```

Here is the expected output:

```
i=2, depth= 0
i=3, depth= 1
i=4, depth= 2
i=5, depth= 3
i=6, depth= 4
i=7, depth= 5
i=8, depth= 6
i=9, depth= 7
i=10, depth= 8
i=11, depth= 9
i=12, depth= 10
```

Comment: If you implement this using a while loop you have none of these issues. Recursion is awesome, but a `while` loop might work just as well here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `local` function to do the same thing but without modifying the global environment:

```
testfun <- local({
  i <- 1
  function( depth= 0 ) {
    i <<- i + 1
    cat( sprintf( "i= %d, depth= %d\n", i, depth ) )
    if( depth < 10 ) testfun( depth + 1 )
  }
})
```

This very neatly wraps the `testfun` function in a *local* environment which holds `i`.  This method should be acceptable in packages submitted CRAN, whereas modifying the global environment is not.

Comment: Nice trick, alleviates at least some of the global assignment problems.

Answer (score 6):

OK, so I'm not very bright. Here is the answer:

```
i <<- i + 1
```

Comment: Clearly you are bright-- after all, you did figure it out :-)

Comment: Note that your function's parent should be the global environment for this to work as you intend. If your function is defined within another function and i is defined there, then the increment will happen to your function's parent environment's i. I hope I dint confuse you.. :)

Comment: Why isn't <<- here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Operators ?

Comment: It is here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Infix-and-prefix-operators

Answer (score 0):

Give "i" as an argument to function.

Comment: The real world problem is more complicated and would require passing large objects as arguments, and R does not pass by reference.

Comment: @January I don't think it's all that bad an idea, albeit not fully worked out. You don't need to pass any objects other than the counter, and then at the "end" of the recursion, include the count value (`depth` in your example) as a list element or some such part of your "large objects."   So, unless there's some overriding reason that you need the count to be assigned to a global variable that's *not* returned from your function, this answer could be useful.